# How to invoke the help function with optparse-c

Tags: c, argv

I am trying to use the [optparse-c library](http://www.orangeclawhammer.net/optparse/optparse-c.tar.gz). This library seems to me quite useful. What I find not
so clear is how to invoke the help without calling `prog -h`.
I can do it if I remove the keyword `static` from the function signature `static void printopts(FILE *f)` in
`optparse.c`, then I could do:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;

    opt_basename(argv[0], '/');
    if (opt_parse("usage: %s [options] arg1 arg2", options, argv) != 2) {
        printopts(stderr);

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ...
```

However, it seems to me the author of this library had some other idea how to invoke the help function. I would be happy if someone could help me figure this out.

I also tried this:

```
char h[] = "-h";
opt_basename(argv[0], '/');
if (opt_parse("usage: %s [options] arg1 arg2", options, argv) != 2) {
    argc++;
    strcpy(argv[1], h);
    opt_parse("usage: %s [options] arg1 arg2", options, argv);

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: You could send a fake `argv` into it, with "-h" as the only option.

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but I could not figure out how to copy a string to argv[1], can you maybe post an example?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if it modifies `argv` or not, but I'd wager that if it doesn't, you could do something like `char* fake_argv[2] = {};` and `fake_argv[0] = argv[0];` and `fake_argv[1] = "-h";`

Comment: @StoryTeller, I tried your code, but it crashes with segmentation fault. I am completely lost here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh well, after a lot of poking and looking into the source code, I found out the not trivial (as I am still learning C) solution:

```
if (opt_parse("usage: %s [options] arg1 arg2", options, argv) != 2) {

        opt_help(0, (void *)0);

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Comment: Big +1 from me for posting the answer after figuring it out. Just one note, the `C`  standard defines the macro `NULL` to be used as the zero value of pointers. Using that instead of `(void *)0` will make your code more idiomatic.

Comment: @StoryTeller, thanks for that! I did not know that is the meaning of NULL!